# How to show ion-progress-bar value inside the bar

Tags: angular, progress-bar, ionic5

I cant find a solution so far for something that should be so jolly simple.

I need to show the percentage value within the active progress bar but just cant seem to get it right.

[Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-simple-progress-bar-component-in-ionic-2/) has this example which is visually what we need to achieve.

Here is what I have. The  div that I have commented out works but I need it to show inside the actual bar.

```
<!-- <div class="showPercentProgress"> {{ percentageValue }}%</div> -->
        
<ion-progress-bar color="primary" type="determinate" [value]="progressStatus"> 
      {{ percentageValue }}%
</ion-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check out this example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ltyru

This is pretty much same. Can include in ionic as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

ok , so you have to create a component with the command of `ionic generate component` the n you have to put with ion-progress-bar in html  of component ike that:

```
   <div class="progress-container" *ngIf="isLoading">
  <ion-progress-bar [value]="progress"></ion-progress-bar>
  <div class="progress-label">{{ progress * 100 | number:'1.0-0' }}%</div>
</div>
```

i choose my css of the progressbar,for example it can be like that:

```
    .progress-container {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000; // Change to match your design
}
```

then for the code of the component you can to put this :

```
    import {Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserCrudService} from "../services/user/user-crud.service";
import {ProgressService} from "../progress.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-bar',
  templateUrl: './progress-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-bar.component.scss']
})
export class ProgressBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() progress: number = 0;
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  private loadingSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private progressService: ProgressService) {

    this.progressService.currentProgress.subscribe(progress => this.progress = progress);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingSub = this.progressService.isLoading.subscribe(loading => {
      this.isLoading = loading;
    });
  }
}
```

now , then , you have to create  a service with `ionic generate service` who link your HttpClient request. In the service class you put code like that :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProgressService {
  isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private progressSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  currentProgress = this.progressSource.asObservable();

  changeProgress(progress: number) {
    this.progressSource.next(progress);
  }
}
```

and then with your request , link at all like that for the count of the ion-progress-bar  :

```
      constructor(private progressService: ProgressService,private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }
```

that's the constructor and then, the request who return an Observable object:
:

```
 putDemiDay(jourTravail: JourTravail): Observable<any> {
    const data: any = {jourTravail: jourTravail};
    let drapeau: boolean;
    const datas = JSON.stringify(data);
    this.progressService.isLoading.next(true);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.endpoint + '/jdt/createJTravail', datas, {
      headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader(), reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    }).pipe(tap(
        event => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            this.progressService.changeProgress(progress);
            console.log(event);
          } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log('insertion des presences de demi journées effectuée');
            this.progressService.isLoading.next(false);
            console.log(event);
          }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError('impossible d\'enregistrer les demijournées')));
  }
```

look what I did in the pipe function.now , don't forget to create  a progress-bar.module.ts file you  have to declare and export your component , the code is :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProgressBarComponent } from './progress-bar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProgressBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ProgressBarComponent
  ]
})
export class ProgressBarModule { }
```

so , now you have to import you ProgressBarModule in the module where you want to display the progress bar like that :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        PresencePageRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ProgressBarModule
    ],
```

and then in your html of the  module where you want to display the progress bar , you put this html code :

it for the  component ProgressBar, have you another questions ?

Comment: if there are missing packages don't forget to install them !